# Deleting Migration Files and Getting django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError:

Tags: python, django

I have deleted all of migration files and now I am trying to `$ python manage.py makemigrations` but it is returning `django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration notifications.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('blog', '0012_auto_20201118_22 55')`

How should I fix this error and start migrating from the beginning? The reason for deleting the migration files is due to removing a function that kept returning an error due one of the migration files so I decided to start clean with them.

Any ideas on what step I should take to start migrations and migrate again?

Comment: Did you delete the migrations for **all** of your applications?

Comment: You might need to delete also tables in the database.

Comment: @ElrondSupportsMonica no just one related to Blog

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan I tried deleting the db but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your **`notifications`** app references model(s) within your **`blog`** app, which means that it has migration files that are *dependent* on **`blog`**.

To fix this you will need to clear the migrations for **all** of your apps, and delete your database.
It's also a good idea to delete your `__pycache__` folders (they have caused migration issues for me in the past).

If you are using a *unix-like* command line, you can do this easily with the following:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -path "*/site-packages/*" -delete
find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation it makes sense now